# PHPWord add text / line break in addCell

Tags: php, format, line, line-breaks, phpword

I'm looking for a  way to add a line break for a text within a cell.
I have 2 variables, `$FirstName = 'Hello';` and `$LastName = 'World'`. I want to make it like :

```
Hello
World
```

The value for styles are :

```
$StyleCell = array('borderTopSize'=>8, 'borderLeftSize'=>8, 'borderRightSize'=>8);
$StyleText = array('size' => 10, 'bold' => true, 'valign' => 'center', 'align' => 'left');
```

I tried `$table->addCell(4000, $StyleCell)->addText($FirstName. PHP_EOL . $LastName , $StyleText);` but it only gives me `Hello World` in the cell. Which it did not work.

Anybody know knows what should I do for I tried `$table->addCell(4000, $StyleCell)->addText($FirstName. /*?? What should I do ???*/ . $LastName, $StyleText);` so it will become like :

```
Hello
World
```

I also tried ""\r\n"" or "\n" also did not work.

I'm using PHPWord 0.13.0

Comment: Are you' working with an Excel spread sheet or a table in a Word document?

Comment: I'm looking in word document, which is I need a line break in a cell for a table

Answer (score 0):

You can use '<w:br />' to break line.

```
$table->addCell(4000, $StyleCell)->addText($FirstName <w:br />$LastName , $StyleText);
```

For this example, the word file show:

$FirstName

$LastName